# Macro called in header generating " Expected identifier or '(' "

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, parse-error

When the `CGRectDivideWithPadding` macro is called like this in the `.h` file:

```
CG_INLINE
void CGRectDivideWithPadding(CGRect rect, CGRect *slicePtr, CGRect *remainderPtr, CGFloat sliceAmount, CGFloat padding, CGRectEdge edge)
{
    CGRectDivideWithUsefulPadding(rect, slicePtr, remainderPtr, nil, sliceAmount, padding, edge);
}
```

it generates an `Expected identifier or '('` error.

The macro is expanded from the `.m` here:

```
#define CGRectDivideWithPadding(RECT, SLICE, REMAINDER, AMOUNT, PADDING, EDGE) \
    do { \
        CGRect _slice, _remainder; \
        CGRectDivideWithPadding((RECT), &_slice, &_remainder, (AMOUNT), (PADDING), (EDGE)); \
        \
        _MEDAssignToRectByReference(SLICE, _slice); \
        _MEDAssignToRectByReference(REMAINDER, _remainder); \
    } while (0)
```

Is there's something wrong with the syntax here that I'm not seeing? Or is the problem elsewhere? How can I clear this up?

Comment: Hmm... Archimedes includes that macro in its header.  Try pulling the latest version.

Comment: @CodaFi I'm pulling `Archimedes` directly from the `:head`. Maybe I need to roll back a version?

Comment: I would say it's because HTGraphicsUtilities, Archimedes, and Core Graphics are all clashing into the same namespace.  Check your imports and make sure that Archimedes is isolated.